# How can I include the degrees and minutes symbols in Java?

Tags: java, utf-8

Do anyone know the code for a character that is used for coordinates, i.e. longitude and lattitude? Its similar to the symbol for celsius, like an 'o'

I suspect that there's a code for it with a backslash. (\xxxxx)

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`\u00B0`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b0/index.htm), the degree symbol. It may be used for temperature and angular location as is being done in your case.

You should *not* use an apostrophe to indicate minutes of arc. Use [`\u2032`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2032/index.htm), the [prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_symbol). If you use an apostrophe, the result *might* look right, but it may also fail to be useful to a crawler or screen-reader.

Seconds likewise should use [`\u2033`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2033/index.htm), the double prime. Do not use a double quotation mark.

The image below shows a comparison of the two symbols as rendered:

[image: Comparison of prime and apostrophe]

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the degree symbol U+00B0.

Answer (score 2):

```
U+00B0
```

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm

It's referred to as the degree sign.

Answer (score 0):

To get the degree symbol in Java just press--

**Alt 0176** and you will get the symbol **°**